# Trying to combine two DE and getting violation of primary key error

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to combine two data extensions into a master data extension. We use email address as a primary key. I setup the query below:

```
select
[EmailAddress] AS [Email],[FirstName] AS [First Name],[LastName] AS [Last Name],[Account] AS [Company Name],[Job Title] AS [Job Title],[Phone] AS [Phone],[Address] AS [Address],[City] AS [City],[State] AS [State Province],[ZipCode] AS [Zip Code],[Country] AS [Country]
from Filter_CorporateCustomer
union
select
[Email] AS [Email],[First Name] AS [First Name],[Last Name] AS [Last Name],[Account] AS [Company Name],[Job Title] AS [Job Title],[Phone] AS [Phone],[Street Address] AS [Address],[City] AS [City],[State Province] AS [State Province],[Zip Postal Code] AS [Zip Code],[Country] AS [Country]
from E_Corporate
```

The query fails: **Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object.**

I obviously have duplicate emails across the two data extension. Is there a best practice for SQL that I can add the data from the first but not the second if its a duplicate?

Comment: what do you have the  Update Type set to? Also, are these duplicates identical or will these need to be unique entries?

Comment: Update type is set to "Update." They don't need to be unique entries, I'd just prefer to use the entry from the first data extension.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go the left joining should be email and not emailaddress

```
select
[EmailAddress] AS [Email],[FirstName] AS [First Name],[LastName] AS [Last Name],[Account] AS [Company Name],[Job Title] AS [Job Title],[Phone] AS [Phone],[Address] AS [Address],[City] AS [City],[State] AS [State Province],[ZipCode] AS [Zip Code],[Country] AS [Country]
from Filter_CorporateCustomer f
LEFT JOIN E_Corporate e ON  f.[EmailAddress] = e.[Email] 
WHERE e.[Email] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a primary violation 
Try this:

```
select
[EmailAddress] AS [Email],[FirstName] AS [First Name],[LastName] AS [Last Name],[Account] AS [Company Name],[Job Title] AS [Job Title],[Phone] AS [Phone],[Address] AS [Address],[City] AS [City],[State] AS [State Province],[ZipCode] AS [Zip Code],[Country] AS [Country]
from Filter_CorporateCustomer f
LEFT JOIN
E_Corporate e 

ON  f.[EmailAddress] = e.[EmailAddress] 

WHERE e.[EmailAddress] IS NULL
```

This will exclude contacts that are already present in the first DE.

Comment: The syntax keeps coming up invalid. Since I matched up the column names for the first data extension, wouldn't I have to do the same for the bottom to ensure that when they join together everything falls in the correct column?

Comment: Can you please post the full error? I have looked through it and it seems fine.  You dont need to going on all columns just one for this query.

Comment: I receive: 
The query syntax is invalid
from is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

Comment: And if I get rid of "from" after Left Join then I'm getting invalid column name errors.

Comment: Missed that , the second from should not be there

Comment: Tried it again...might be because I didnt put the `EmailAddress` fields in parentheses